# A better concurrent prime number sieve in go

Tags: algorithm, go

After looking at the prime number sieve code, and seeing how the
concurrent structure works, I found it to be extremely elegant.
However, it's also extremely inefficient, and IIRC, equivalent to the
O(n^2) operation of testing the divisibility of the number m by
dividing it by every number less than m. I figure that I could instead
modify it to use the O(n^1.5) operation of checking the divisibility
of m by dividing it by every number less than or equal to the sqrt(m).
However, this turned out to be a lot harder than I anticipated.

I know this is more of an algorithmics question, but it's also one
extremely relevant to concurrency. How would one implement the
O(n^1.5) version of the algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One place to look is [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), for example, the question [Concurrent Prime Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89705/concurrent-prime-generator). Amongst the  answers is one that uses [Go and channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89705/concurrent-prime-generator/2391751#2391751).

Answer (score 1):

Elegant but inefficient prime sieve implementations are already well known to the Functional Programming community. This [paper](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) by Melissa O’Neill gives a good overview of lazy "stream" prime sieves as well as presenting efficient alternatives. (It uses Haskell, but should be a good read anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Eratosthenes' sieve identifies prime p_i at iteration i and prunes all multiples of p_i from consideration in successive iterations.  Given that, the only thing you can parallelise here is the pruning operation.  This can only be sped up by a constant factor, so you won't change the big-O of the algorithm this way.

Comment: in general concurrent implementation of a given algorithm are not superlinear. At best, they just speed up the algorithm proportionally to the number of parallel workers. One notable exception are `find`-like algorithms.